# Creating a git Branch after changes have been made to master

Tags: git, version-control

I started doing work in master - many changes later (no commits) I realized that this work should be done in a separate branch.

Can I create a new branch with my current changes, then discard the changes in master back to its pristine state?

Thanks

Comment: +1 I wonder why would someone down vote this question, its clear and I had the same one. As a newbie to git its not that obvious and I was afraid of branching and loosing my changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

while on master:

```
git branch [new-branch]
git checkout [new-branch]
```

...continue editing - in my case I committed them...

```
git add .
git commit -am 'updates'
```

switch back to master

```
git checkout master
```

Branch was in original state before I started making all the changes...

Hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: Or: `git checkout -b [new-branch]` instead of your first two commands.